# Why are preflight OPTIONS requests for Outlook REST API calls sometimes rejected?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

We are developing an Outlook Web App add-in.
We followed the procedure to create an add-in through the official documentation and so far, this has worked... reasonably well.

Right now, we are experiencing intermittent failing OPTIONS pre-flight (CORS) requests *only* on localhost, to the following endpoint:

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{itemId}`.

Our specific query looks like this:

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{itemId}?$expand=attachments($select=Name,Size,IsInline,ContentType)`

this is the error:

[image: request error]

these are the request details:

[image: request details]

This started suddenly happening, since this week (mon 23 july 2018)

Related, should we include `Access-Control-Max-Age` to have the browser not make too many OPTIONS requests ?

Comment: We're getting the same error message in our web application, using ADAL JS for authentication. We're currently only receiving the error specifically from the outlook api endoint. The weird thing is that we get the errors in about 50% of the total requests.

Comment: If possible, could you please provide more details about this error, like, in which mode the add-in is running, mail or calendar, read or compose? Code snippet could be helpful too. Thanks

Comment: This was occurring for us in `mail` mode and in both `compose` and `read` modes. I will look into providing a code snippet, but, I can't help to replicate browser behaviour, which is exactly what the OPTIONS request is...

Comment: Are you able to successfully make a CORS request outside of the add-in? What scenario are you trying to implement?

Comment: yes. If I go to https://resttesttest.com/ and craft a simple request with auth and random headers, a pre-flight OPTIONS request is triggered by OSX chrome, which, after hitting 30 times, goes perfectly fine each time.

Comment: Which scenario? we're just using the OfficeJs REST API to get the current mail item: `${app.owaRestUrl}/v2.0/me/messages/${id}/?$expand=attachments($select=Name,Size,IsInline,ContentType)`
also without Odata selectors this fails occasionally.